# Using Stored Procedures in Flask

Tags: python, stored-procedures, flask

I am very much a newbie to python programming I am trying to implement store procedure in flask.

This is the part of the code from where i am calling the stored procedure.

```
        cursor.execute(insertquery)
        database.commit()
        cursor2.execute("select id from users where userid='"+username1+"'")
        data2=cursor2.fetchall()
        dictionary1=[dict(user=row[0]) for row in data2]
        for data in dictionary1:
            user_store=int((data.get('user')))
        cursor2.callproc('insertPrediction',user_store)
        database.commit()
        database.close()
```

and this is the stored procedure

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `S3UploadDB`.`insertPrediction`;
PROCEDURE `S3UploadDB`.`insertPrediction`(IN id int(20))
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO prediction(id,matchno,winner,points)
        VALUES (id,1,'na',-500);
END;
```

when even i am invoking the procedure from toad it is working fine and the data is getting updated 
but when ever it is getting invoked from the python code

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

It is failing at this line of the code

```
cursor2.callproc('insertPrediction',user_store)
```

I have converted the value to INT before passing it as the input to the stored procedure is of type `int`. I am using MySQL
Please help me on this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`callproc` requires a sequence of arguments such as a list or tuple, even if there is only one argument. Use:

```
cursor2.callproc('insertPrediction', [user_store])
```

[Link to docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-callproc.html).